# Excel: How to find rows on different sheets with same data --> change data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 5 sheets.
Sheet1 is a master list with 4 columns (id, name, value, available), it has the contents of the other 4 sheets, sorted by value.
Sheets2-5 have the same 4 columns (id, name, value, available).  Every entry on sheet1 has exactly 1 alike (alike only by name) entry somewhere on Sheet2-5.

The "Available" column is binary (either "yes" or "no").  On sheet1 I have a conditional format rule that turns the any row with a "no" in the "Available" column red.

I would like the alike row on Sheet2-5 to automatically change its "Available" column to "no" so that the conditional formatting rule I place on that sheet as well, takes effect.

How can I find the alike row on the other sheet?  And how can I make its "Available" column, automatically change to "no"?

Comment: Use a vlookup() on sheets 2-5 to return the "Available" value from Sheet1 (looking up "name").